# Unable to make Canary Deployment with API Gateway and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, canary-deployment

I am trying to use the Canary deployment option of API Gateway, but I am not being able to do so. It looks like all the configurations are done properly, but when I try making calls I only get the latest code version responses. To sum up, this is what I am doing:

1. I have a API Gateway stage called *dev*, in which I have a Lambda already deployed. I have added to my base code an endpoint that returns the version of the code currently running.
2. I enable the Canary deployment option in the target stage (*dev*) in the API Gateway Console.
3. I make changes in the code and update the version number in the previously created endpoint.
4. I make a new deploy (Lambda) with the expected Canary settings. In my case, I'm using a *percentTraffic* of 50%.

Everything looks fine, even the percent is changed automatically in the Canary tab in the API Gateway Console. But once I start making calls to my endpoint, I only get the latest version. So it looks like I am missing something, but I don't know what.

Any ideas? :)